# JPA single query to fetch nested collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Java 11 Spring Boot application and I use JPA with Hibernate in it.

```
public class Test {
   (...)

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_id", nullable = false)
    private List<Question> availableQuestions;

   (...)
```

```
public class Question {
    (...)
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
    private List<Answer> availableAnswers;
    (...)
```

```
public class Answer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="answer_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "answer_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "answer_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "text", length = 500)
    private String text;
    @Column(name = "is_correct")
    private boolean isCorrect;
```

Now, in my code, I have a need to fetch a test, and iterate over its availableQuestions and for each question to iterate over its availableAnswers. This produces a nasty n+1 problem, as for each question a separate call is made to fetch the answers.

The question: **What can I do to fetch the test with questions and answers fetched in one query?**

I tried using `fetchType.EAGER` on availableAnswers, but this still produced n queries to get answers for all questions (it just did so earlier, efore the getter was acutally called).
I also tried custom jpql query with join fetch and I also tried an entity graph. Got the `MultipleBagFetchException` from hibernate on both.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Hibernate 5.4.12

Comment: Could you please try using EntityGraph and change one of the List to Set either change `List<Question> to Set<Question>` or ` List<Answer> to Set<Answer>`
once you tested please update here

Comment: Thanks, I changed Lists to Sets and used a custome join fetch query, seems like there is only one DB qyeru run now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to avoid n + 1 problems.

Eager load relation in JPQL `FETCH JOIN` or by using `EntityGraph`.

With join fetch ->

`Select distinct t from Test t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.availableQuestions q LEFT JOIN FETCH q.availableAnswers a`

Regarding `MultipleBagFetchException` to avoid "duplicate" problem you could switch the collection type from `List` type to `Set`.

Comment: as I wrote in the original post - I already tried the fetch join and entity graph approaches. I am getting `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags:`  Your query also produces this exception

Comment: yep it comes from "duplicate" problem. I updated my answer. Could you check ?

Comment: Still, the same exception is thrown

Comment: did you try by replacing `List` by  `Set` ? just take care of equals/hash contract and performance impact (cartesian product)

Comment: Hey, yes, I replaced Lists with Sets now and it seems like there is only one call made. What's the catch here?  What is the performance impact I should take care of and how do I take care of it?

Comment: after reflexion...not sure you'll hve a problem with nested relations....so probably not a cartesian product here. Problem happens when you load multiple one-level graph...

Comment: you could check the generated native query. So it works now ?